# How do I get node revisions to use my custom template?

Tags: theming, 9

I have a custom node template for my content type of Listing, `node--listing.html.twig`. It is quite heavily customised for the client. However when we go to view a revision (e.g. `/node/144/revisions/273/view`) it doesn't seem to bother loading a template at all, not even `node.html.twig` - the fields just get dumped onto the page.

Any ideas how to force it to use the custom template?

Answer (score 0):

You can try my patch from [Make node_is_page() work on revisions and previews as well](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3005029). If that doesn't fix it, you can probably use the relatively simple code update from inside `node_is_page()` to add your own template suggestions using [`hook_theme_suggestions_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I have solved this myself in the end, it WAS using the template, it's just that the `page` flag wasn't set in the revision view and that was causing a default view of the node. So my mistake. But worth remembering that when viewing a revision you get `view_mode == 'full'` and `page == false`

Comment: Where were you using this flag? Preprocess?